# Replacement water shut off valve stem is too short to protrude past the wall board

Tags: plumbing, valve

In my condo, I replaced my old, crusty, main shutoff gate valve with a brand new ball valve.  The only problem is that the distance from the base of the gate valve to the end of its stem is about two inches longer than the distance from the base of the ball valve to the tip of its stem.  So, while the gate valve's stem protruded through the sheet rock wall that covers it, the tip of the stem on the new ball valve is below the sheet rock's surface.  I've seen some valve extenders on-line but they appear to be for a specific brand of valve--I got mine at Lowes, it's an "Everbilt"--and I cannot tell if the one on-line will fit my valve.  Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make the drywall hole a lot bigger or just big enough for your hand to operate the valve & put one of these [**Access Panels**](http://www.lowes.com/pd_115084-138-34053___?productId=3130137&pl=1&Ntt=access%20panels) (left) over the drywall hole. Preferably glued or caulked & drywall anchor screwed, since you need to pry these open with a flathead screwdriver. Or, 1 or 2 (hot & cold) of these [**2-gang electrical outlet covers**](http://www.lowes.com/pd_55761-427-8752___?productId=3129183&Ns=p_product_price%7C0&pl=1&Ntt=2-gang%20cover) (right). These just need 2 screws in the drywall at opposing corners to then just slide up & off...a shot of spray paint to camouflage.

[image: Access Panels]